# Как переменной из вложенного кода if, передать значение на последующий if - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Заранее извиняюсь за столь глупый вопрос, но в программировании я ещё новичок. Подскажите как переменной balance во вложенном коде if step == 5, передать значение balance из it step == 6: Нужно использовать функцию?

```
                if step == 6:
                    balance = int(input("На какую сумму хотите пополнить счет: "))
                    print(f"На вашем балансе сейчас {balance} {currency}")
                if step == 5:
                    if balance > 0:
                        debit = int(input(f"Сколько вы хотите списать с {balance}: "))
                        if debit > balance:
                            print("У вас нет столько средств!")
                        else:
                            debit_result = balance - debit
                            print(f"На вашем счету осталось {debit_result} {currency}")
                    else:
                        print("На вашем счету нет средств")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в лоб, то можно заменить

```
if step == 5:
```

на, к примеру,

```
if step in [5, 6]:
```

Хотя по мне лучше будет сделать класс, в котором будет храниться баланс и сопутствующие атрибуты, а к нему методы, из которых потом набирать логику.

Answer (score 0):

Объяви переменную до if. Просто напиши balance = 0 до ветвлений, должно заработать так как ты хочешь.

Comment: Или ты потом еще и хочешь попасть в if step=5? Тогда еще и в if step=6 поменяй step на 5.